# Embeded Vimeo Video progress Tracking

Tags: video-streaming, vimeo

On one of my website I am using a vimeo video link to show a video. Now I am having a requirement  to track the video progress. like the duration a learner spent on that particular page or the percentage of video viewed by the user. Is it possible to track this in JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

Using `player.js` you can use the below code

```html
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js">
```

```js
const player = new Vimeo.Player("video_id"); 

player.on('timeupdate', function(data){
  console.log( data.seconds );
});
```

Hope it will help you.

I have used it with a WordPress site to track the progress using the code below:

```js
player.on('timeupdate', function(data){
        var running_time = data.seconds;
             $.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php" ) ?>',
                data : {
                    action: "storeinDB",
                    user_id : "<?php echo $user->ID; ?>",
                    post_id : "<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>",
                    running_time : running_time },
                dataType : "post",
                type: "post",
                success: function(response){
                    //console.log(response);
                }
            });
    });
```

thanks

---

Related resources:

- [Tracking progress in embedded Vimeo videos](https://www.urbaninsight.com/article/tracking-progress-embedded-vimeo-videos)

Comment: My only issue with this is that it will be posting to the server every second. I would suggest making the ajax request on a larger interval and maybe storing the up to the second information in a cookie.